# skip token verification for GET request

Tags: node.js, express

I want skip token verification for GET method in express. I want to allow GET request for everyone while just post, put, delete request by authorized user.below is my logic but the response hanging. I tried to used nested express use method.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
if (req.method === 'GET') {

    app.use('/api/someroute', routes);

}
else{
    //do verification below the next
    next();
    }
})
```

or is there any other way to handle this

Comment: Just setup your `GET` routes first then apply your token auth middleware after, any routes beyond that would then be protected.

Comment: i have more than fifty GET request in different route file so its difficult in each method I try the above but express not allowing. I want to try app.use instead app.get in each route

Comment: so just to confirm your entire `/api/someroute` are all `GET` requests?

Comment: get only work with single route while use need sub route

Comment: api/someroute also contain post request but i want to take decision only if method is GET

Answer (score 1):

Just include a middleware on desired routes :

```
var router = express.Router();

// no middleware included for get request
router.get("/route1", handlerRoute1); 
router.get("/route2", handlerRoute2);

// include some middleware
router.post("/route3", myMiddleware1, myMiddleware2, handlerRoute3); 
app.use(router);
```

Where myMiddleware1 and myMiddleware2 looks like :

```
myMiddleware1 = function(req, res, next){
    // verify token, etc, ....

    var success = true;

    // call next on success
    if(success)
      return next();
    else
    {
       // raise error
       return res.status(500).json({error: "Missing token..."});
    }
};
```

Comment: i want app.use coz there are fifty route so router.get("/route1", handlerRoute1);  this will not work

Comment: if method is get then allow if not then verify the token

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the scenario for GET requests you don't actually complete the request (or move on from that middleware). Middleware is processed in sequential order i.e. first come first served. If you only want to protect everything other than GET requests then something like this would be fine:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  // let GET requests through
  if (req.method === 'GET') return next();

  // perform token auth on all other requests, next() if OK
});
// setup routes
app.use('/api/someroute', routes);
```

You would setup your middleware first then declare your routes after, this means any requests coming in will have to pass through your token check, in this case you just skip GET requests.

Comment: Thanks james but i mention i want to protect post and put while all get request want to left unprotected